# xamarin app SIGSEGV error

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, segmentation-fault

developers.

Im new monotouch developer.

My app works fine this code block but suddenly shut down and got this error. Where can i do wrong? How can i solve? Thank you.

```
 NewsElement.Tapped+= delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            try 
            {
                News news=_news.Find(x => x.Title== _section.Elements[NewsElement._indexPath.Row].Caption.ToString());


                using(NewsDetailViewController nDVC=new NewsDetailViewController(news,_newsEnum))
                {

                    this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = ExtensionMethods.ToUIColor("4BC1D2");
                    this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor=UIColor.White;
                    this.NavigationController.PushViewController (nDVC, true);  

                }
            } 
            catch 
            {

            }

        };
```

Error is:

```
mono-rt: Stacktrace:

mono-rt:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>

mono-rt:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00026, 0xffffffff>

mono-rt:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.get_NavigationController () [0x00030] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/build/compat/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:1595

mono-rt:   at HaberOku.MainViewController.<LoadView>m__A (object,System.EventArgs) [0x00029] in /Users/muhammetsahin/Projects/HaberOku/HaberOku/DialogViewControllers/MainViewController.cs:89

mono-rt:   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1.invoke_void__this___object_TEventArgs (object,TEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00087>

mono-rt:   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1.invoke_void__this___object_TEventArgs (object,TEventArgs) <IL 0x00059, 0xffffffff>

mono-rt:   at HaberOku.NewsElement.Selected (MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController,MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView,MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath) [0x00029] in /Users/muhammetsahin/Projects/HaberOku/HaberOku/Elements/NewsElement.cs:61

mono-rt:   at MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController.Selected (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath) [0x00033] in /Users/muhammetsahin/Projects/HaberOku/HaberOku/MonoTouchDialog/DialogViewController.cs:522

mono-rt:   at MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController/Source.RowSelected (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView,MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath) [0x00021] in /Users/muhammetsahin/Projects/HaberOku/HaberOku/MonoTouchDialog/DialogViewController.cs:368

mono-rt:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0005a, 0xffffffff>

mono-rt:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>

mono-rt:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0009f, 0xffffffff>

mono-rt:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38

mono-rt:   at HaberOku.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00009] in /Users/muhammetsahin/Projects/HaberOku/HaberOku/Main.cs:17

mono-rt:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

mono-rt: 
Native stacktrace:


mono-rt: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty strange pattern.  As soon as the block completes, it will dispose of nDVC, even though you have just pushed nDVC onto the navigation stack and are still using it.  Try removing the using() so that nDVC will not be prematurely disposed.

```
            using(NewsDetailViewController nDVC=new NewsDetailViewController(news,_newsEnum))
            {
                this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = ExtensionMethods.ToUIColor("4BC1D2");
                this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor=UIColor.White;
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController (nDVC, true);  
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this kind of error when I was referencing objects that were not alive anymore by the time the delegate was executed.

So maybe you could try to make sure that the objects you are calling are still available/have not been garbage collected. Try sending them in or doing null checks.